# DuoCode and Knockout

Tags: c#, knockout.js, duocode

I'm looking at [DuoCode](http://duoco.de/) as a alternative to TypeScript since it uses C# which means my dev's can use their already existing knowledge with C# but also that we can reuse for example validation logic both on client and server.

Currently there is no Binding for Knockout so I have created my own, it very simple

```
namespace Knockout
{
    [Js(Name = "ko", Extern = true)]
    public static class Global
    {
        [Js(Name = "observable", OmitGenericArgs = true)]
        public static extern Observable<T> Observable<T>();

        [Js(Name = "observable", OmitGenericArgs = true)]
        public static extern Observable<T> Observable<T>(T value);

        [Js(Name = "computed", OmitGenericArgs = true)]
        public static extern Observable<T> Computed<T>(Func<T> computed);

        [Js(Name = "applyBindings")]
        public static extern void ApplyBindings(object viewModel);

        [Js(Name = "unwrap", OmitGenericArgs = true)]
        public static extern T Unwrap<T>(Observable<T> observable);

    }

    [Js(Name = "ko.observable", Extern = true)]
    public class Observable<T>
    {
        //TODO: Add more methods like subscribe, extend etc
    }
}
```

Here is a simple model using it

```
namespace ViewModels
{

    public class FooViewModel
    {
        public FooViewModel()
        {
            Bar = Global.Observable("HelloWorld");
            Computed = Global.Computed(() => Global.Unwrap(Bar) + "COMPUTED");
        }

        public Observable<string> Bar { get; set; }
        public Observable<string> Computed { get; set; }
    }
}
```

The Computed func can use the underlying observable value using `Global.Unwrap` which translates to `ko.unwap` on the client

But for setting value I have not come up with a solid solution, only soltution that I have found is

```
Js.referenceAs<Action<string>>("this.Bar")("New Value");
```

Which have way to many drawbacks to be the accepted solution

Any ideas?

edit: Extension method makes it a little nicer, but with the downside that you now need to include the javascript compiled with the Knockout binding class library

```
public static class ObservableExtensions
{
    public static void SetValue<T>(this Observable<T> observable, T value)
    {
        Js.referenceAs<Action<T>>("observable")(value);
    }
}
```

**Thoughts on Yoav's answer**

1. Better than referenceAs, but too verbose and too little type safety
2. JsFunction basicly same as above
3. Seems like the best solution then

I now have this

```
public static class ObservableExtensions
{
    public static void Set<T>(this Observable<T> observable, T value)
    {
        observable.As<Action<T>>()(value);
    }

    public static T Get<T>(this Observable<T> observable)
    {
        return observable.As<Func<T>>()();
    }
}
```

Its a bit sad since it introduces a extra function call that is not needed

```
Knockout.ObservableExtensions.Set(String, this.get_Bar(), "New value");
```

Instead of just

```
this.get_Bar()("New value");
```

**I have another question**, I'm also looking at knockout Observable Arrays, I have this

```
[Js(Name = "ko.observableArray", Extern = true)]
public class ObservableArray<T> : Observable<JsArray<T>>
{
    [Js(Name = "push", OmitGenericArgs = true)]
    public extern void Push(T value);
}
```

And on my Global KO static class I have

```
[Js(Name = "observableArray", OmitGenericArgs = true)]
public static extern ObservableArray<T> ObservableArray<T>(T[] values);
```

I have tried different values for the method argument like JsArray, IEnumerable etc, they all produce the same code on client

```
ko.observableArray($d.array(System.Int32, [1, 2, 3, 4]));
```

This will fail because Knockout observable array expects a normal Javascript array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend the following:

1. Instead of using **Js.referenceAs** you can use the **As** extension method like this: `Bar.As<Action<string>>()("New Value");`
2. Another option is to make **Observable** inherit from **JsFunction**, and then you can call *invoke* like this: `Bar.invoke("New Value");`
3. Another option is to the same just inside an extension method, similar to what you've suggested. Define a method like this:

   ```
   public static void Set<T>(this Observable<T> o, T value)
   {
     o.As<Action<T>>()(value);
   }
   ```

   (Note that it must be an extension method because the *Observable* class is extern, so define this method in a different static class)
   And then you can use it like this: `Bar.Set("New value");`

Also I would recommend making **Bar** a field instead of a property (it will generate a cleaner code)

(Disclosure: I work with the DuoCode developers)

**Edit**

I agree, the extension method is the best option at the moment. Maybe in the near future they will support something like this:

```
[Js(Name="")]
public void SetValue(T value)
```

Regarding your second question: looking at the code in mscorlib.js, `$d.array` creates normal arrays (just with some extra properties for runtime type information). The problem here is that it creates *typed-arrays* for types like *Int32*. So I guess you can create an *object* array instead of *T* and it should work, like this:

```
[Js(Name = "observableArray", OmitGenericArgs = true)]
public static extern ObservableArray<T> ObservableArray<T>(object[] values);
```

Comment: you dont have any input on the array stuff?

Comment: I think this should help, please let me know if it did

Comment: Will try it when I get home, but ouch, removing the type safety feels like a big loss :/

Comment: I agree, it's not optimal.

Comment: I opened a ticket, thanks for the help http://support.duoco.de/support/tickets/1061